# After exporting SSRS report into excel I need to see 2 different headers in 2 tabs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report with 2 Tablix in it, I used a page break property to export the data into 2 different tabs in excel it’s works fine, After exporting the report into excel I need to see 2 different headers in 2 tabs?

Comment: Can you just add a row above each tablix with your header info in it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the requirement is to show the heading in the report header only

Comment: The way I might try it would be to remove the page header altogether and create "fake" page headers in the top rows of each tablix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header section you can use a placeholder and set the contents dynamically using an expression.
Following expression should get the desired result:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber=1,"Heading1","Heading2")
```

Taking into consideration you are using excel export you will most likely have only two pages so the above code should work.

Comment: Many thanks @Iker, since it's monthly report the data would be changing month on month, we can't go with the pagenumbers

Comment: Instead of Page number, i used Page name it work's fine for now.. :), Thanks for the solution